# Streams deployed with direct binding still send messages to rabbitMQ

Tags: spring-xd

I deployed a stream with "module.*.count=0" deployment descritptor in order to force direct binding. It happens by using rabbitmq-trace that there are messages going through rabbit however I see less messages than if direct binding option was disabled. Is this the expected behavior?

I thought, by reading the docs, that nothing would go through external bus in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not see any rabbit traffic for such a case.

When a producer (source, processor) is bound, the rabbit binding is converted to a direct binding if possible (this container has an appropriate matching consumer [sink, processor], which should happen with `count=0`).

Take a look at the logs, while deploying the producer module, successful conversions will result in this log...

```
logger.info("Producer bound directly: " + binding);
```

If the consumer doesn't exist, you'll see

```
logger.info("declaring queue for outbound: " + name);
```

Comment: You are right about that logger info stuff however there is still traffic going to rabbit. Although the message is just published and its not received. Maybe that has to do with the message needing to be available for taping. Do you know anything about this? When I dont deploy in memory I get 2 published messages and 1 received in rabbit trace.

Comment: Hmmm... nothing should go to rabbit, even for the tap, until the first tap consumer is deployed. Can you post a DEBUG level log somewhere showing the deployment log messages as well as messages subsequently going to rabbit?

Comment: Ok I think I fixed it now. I tried to create a new stream with a different name but with the same definition and I noticed that no messages where going to rabbit. I destroyed all and created those 2 again and still the first was publishing to rabbit. Thinking it might be a cache problem I deleted the data folder of XD with no success. Then I tried to delete the data folder of zookeeper and it worked. Now it's working ok. Thank you for your help. It pushed me in the right direction (ps: I haven't voted up because I don't have enough reputation to do so. Sorry)

Comment: NP; glad you figured it out.